# The frequency is off by a factor of $2 \pi$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, definition, frequency, oscillators, angular-velocity

I was reading Morin's Introduction to Mechanics, and the following material came up:

At equilibrium point $x_0$ expanding the Taylor series, we see $V(x)=\frac12 V''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2$ so comparing this with $V$ for spring, we see that the equation of motion is $\sin(\omega t)$ where $\omega^2=\frac{V''(x_0)}{m}$.

Till here, everything is clear but then he says that the frequency of small oscillations is therefore $\omega = \sqrt\frac{V''(x_0)}{m}$

Now this is where my trouble is, by looking at the equation of motion $\sin(\omega t)$ the frequency should actually be $\frac{\omega}{2\pi}$ but he says the frequency is just simply $\omega$.

I have seen this in a lot of problems I am doing also, if I get that the force on a particle is $F=-kx$, they say frequency is $\sqrt\frac{k}{m}$, but time period is always defined as $\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$

So my question is basically what am I missing, the frequency, that is 1/time period is of course $\frac{\omega}{2\pi}$ so why do so many problems and books say the frequency is $\omega$...

Is it just two different uses of the same word, if so what is expected when someone asks for frequency of oscillations?

Comment: He means angular frequency. A lot of people are sloppy about the distinction, and angular frequency is often the more useful and simple quantity. Unfortunately, in every case you need to infer from context which one people really mean.

Comment: In published work I sometimes report a numerical value of $\omega$ by writing something like "$\omega = 2\pi \times 10$ MHz". In this kind of presentation the MHz unit refers to the value 10, so you can see the frequency is 10 MHz, but meanwhile it is also clear that $\omega$ is the angular frequency (whose value in this example is about $62.83 \times 10^6$ rad/s).

Comment: @knzhou wow that clears my query.. btw on a tangential note,i got excited about physics olympiad after reading your phyoly guide... lately i was feeling quiet annoyed since i wasn't able to make progress at the rate i wanted to and a lot of things felt confusing. i was feeling quite annoyed that i couldnt solve some realtively simple physics problems when i could solve so many tough math olympiad problems, but your comment reminded me of why i actually started doing this, that's because i enjoy physics and wanna get good at it, so thank you, back to work now, with a clear goal, enjoy physics

Comment: "what is expected when someone asks for frequency of oscillations?" It depends on who's asking. A teacher in a school would expect you to give *f* in Hz. At a more advanced level you might want to play it safe by giving *f* in Hz and also giving  in rad s$^{−1}$.